# Runtime error occurs while loading Addthis widget asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, addthis

I integrated s7.addthis in one of website which I am working in below manner.

```
var addthis_config = { "data_track_addressbar": false };
    $(window).load(function () {
        $.getScript("//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5141f14b7b88c783");
    });
```

This is working fine till yesterday. But now it is showing error **$__$ is undefined**. You can notice same in below image.

[image]
Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am Ribin from AddThis support team. I could reproduce the issue. I have created a ticket assigned to the developers to address the issue. I will update you as soon as I get a response from the team.

Thank for reporting this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response Ribin. let me know resolution as soon as possible. once again thanks !

Comment: We are getting this error as well. Mostly often the error is occurring in Chrome, but it's also happening in Firefox and Safari (including iOS). Here are the two different points we are seeing the error from: `https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js:7:15863` and `https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js:7:31672`. Any chance there is a place to track the issue or provide additional information that might help resolve it? We had to remove AddThis from a lot of pages because the number of users receiving the error was 75% of all traffic!

Comment: Hi Nate.. When I posted this issue, it is replicated in IE11. But now this is working fine in all browsers [IE, CHROME, FIREFOX, SAFARI(ON WINDOWS - DESKTOP)]. I think this is resolved in backend by AddThis team. Here we need to thank Ribin for initiating this with their Dev team.